# Google Map directions APi Alternitives?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

Me and My group are  doing a Map project for my University Campus. we considered using google maps and its directions apit to do building to building and user location to building and eventually room to room. the problem is that because the paths on our campus are not mapped so unless we do manual routes and that would take to long. is there any alternative map/directions Api that we anc use that woudl just as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this [top-10-mapping-apis](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/top-10-mapping-apis-google-maps-microsoft-bing-maps-and-mapquest/analysis/2015/02/23) and this [Comparison_of_web_map_services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_map_services)

i suggest u to use mapquest.